# How to incrementally update a table

Tags: hadoop, hive

We're using Hive and have a data flow that looks like:

```
 SOURCE -> Flume -> S3 Buckets -> Script -> Hive Table
```

We have a table that looks something like, truncated for brevity:

```
 CREATE TABLE core_table (
       unique_id string
       update bigint
       other_data string
 )
```

Now we also have the update table - same structure `core_update` this table may contain duplicated data (e.g. duplicated unique_id, but increasing bigint, also it's ordered later int the file).

Is there a good way to apply the updated that are in `core_update` to `core_table` while both adding new unique_id's to the table and updating the base data.

-- Note: I am trying to avoid something that looks like: MERGE -> DEDUP since that process takes about 3 hours on the smaller datasets, and we've got one dataset that is whomping huge. So doing something that's akin to an insertion sort would be great.

Update:  Found the following blog post by IBM http://ibm.co/15bMSxk And it says:

Algorithm-2: Update into un-partitioned table

- Step-1
  Run the merge join query Input : mainTable, staging table name to hold merged records(call as stagingTable3), un-partitioned staging table name(call as stagingTable2), table primary key, table fields
  Build the merge join query:

  insert overwrite table stagingTable3
  select each column in "List tableFields"
  Add field name with the alias A
  from mainTable with alias A
  Apply the left outer join with stagingTable2 with alias B
  Check for where A.primaryKey = B.primaryKey and where B.primaryKey is null

  Then union with the data selected from stagingTable2
- Step-2: Load the data by overwriting from stagingTable3 to mainTable by using the below given load query:

  ```
  load data inpath stagingTable3 overwrite into mainTable
  ```

However this still doesn't quite make sense (or work in my interpretation).